# How does one control an animated SVG in Unity 3D?

Tags: animation, svg, unity-game-engine

I have an animated SVG file that contains 400 frames of animation. I'd like to put this asset in my game, and control which frames playback and when like a file strip / animated GIF. I have the asset imported using SVGAssets.

Is there a way to do this? I've looked in the Unity documentation, but it continually points me at standard 2D assets or normal 3D FBX files.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG animations are not supported by SVGAssets plugin, at the moment. The usual workflow would be to import SVG static graphics with SVGAssets, then animate it with Unity tools (as done for the Orc example included in the SVGAssets package).